# fwrite/fread doesn't work well in Windows

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I wrote a program in that create a structure variable, then write it in a file using the function `fwrite`. The returned code is 1 (I wrote just one structure variable). When I tried to read the file with `fread` function it returns `0` and the variable is not filled completely.

This problem is specific for windows only. I tried the same code with Linux (Ubuntu virtual machine) and it worked well.

Here is the structure:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char comment[40];
    int nbpts;
    float time[4096];
    float value[4096];
};

FILE* fp = fopen(fileTrace, "w");
fwrite(&var, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, fp);


fread(&var, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, fp);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not checking any return values from those functions, which you should. Also, Windos likes to have binary files opened as "wb"/"rb" to suppress interpretation of binary.

Comment: What about `fseek` function to move pointer for reading?

Comment: you should close and re-open the file for reading in between the `fwrite` and `fread` otherwise your reading from the end of the file *and* can't read cos you've opened the file in write-only mode

Comment: Use `"wb"` and `"rb"` for mode of `fopen`.

Comment: "and it worked well" how do you know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the file for reading too:

```
fopen(..., "w+")
```

And you should open it in binary mode, so `fwrite`/`fread` doesn't do any funky character conversions (e.g. platform specific line-endings for Windows):

```
fopen(..., "w+b")
```

If you want to `fread` directly after a `fwrite` you have to reset the file pointer position, so that `fread` starts reading from where you have written your data.

To summarize:

```
   if ((fp = fopen("var.dat", "w+b")) != NULL) {
      fwrite(&var, sizeof(var), 1, fp);
      rewind(fp);
      memset(&var, 0, sizeof(var)); // reset var
      fread(&var, sizeof(var), 1, fp);
      // ...          
      fclose(fp);
   }
```

*(This examples uses `rewind` to set the file pointer to the beginning, you might have to use [fseek](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek) instead)*

---

**A word of caution:** To be portable, you should not write a struct directly to disk, but actually serialize it (i.e. manually write out every field to the file, maybe prefixed with a small header), since compiler-specific padding might (or will) cause problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{
    const char *pFIle = "test.txt";
    char var[sizeof(struct MyStruct)] = {0};
    int ret = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(pFIle, "w+");
    ret = fwrite(&var, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, fp);
    printf("fwrite ret =%d;\r\n", ret);
    fflush(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ret = fread(&var, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, fp);
    printf("fread ret =%d;\r\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

I have test, everything is OK on windows. Let me know if you have other problems.

Comment: Please explain why your solution works instead of just dumping code.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I am sorry, English is not my native language, I am afraid that if I explain too much may make more mistake or misunderstand, so, I put more code instead of explain. Sorry!